# Determining if this integral converge

Tags: calculus

Does the following integral converge:

$$\ \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)dx $$

my attempt:

$$\  \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx \ge \int_1^\infty \frac{-x}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{-1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx \ge -1 \cdot \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}}dx = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2}} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x} $$

and since I know $\ \frac{1}{x} $ doesn't converge, the integral also doesn't??

Comment: No.  You've shown the value of the integral is $\ge-\infty$ which doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\  \int_1^\infty \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \right)dx
& = & \int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx  \\
& = & \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}(\sqrt{x^2+1} + x)}dx  \\
& \stackrel{\sqrt{x^2+1}\geq x}{\leq} & \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x\cdot x (x+x)}dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{2x^3}dx < \infty
\end{eqnarray*}

So, it is convergent.

Answer (score 2):

For large $x$, we see by Taylor expansion that $$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} = x\sqrt{1 + \frac 1 {x^2}} \approx x\left(1 + \frac 1 {2x^2}\right).$$ Thus $$\sqrt{x^2 + 1} - x \approx \frac1{2x},$$ so as $x \to \infty$, we have $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+1}-x}{x\sqrt{x^2+1}} \approx \frac{1/(2x)}{x^2}\approx \frac{1}{2x^{3}}.$$ Hence the integral converges by comparison with $$\int^\infty_{1}\frac{dx}{2x^{3}}.$$